# Percentile of durations per day over month

Tags: indexing, match, percentile

I am trying to find the percentile of durations per day. I have a large table with 10's of thousands of rows. It is laid out similar to the attached image. I want to add a column D that would tell me the percentile of the row against all the matching dates as that row, ie row 2 is 8/1 so compare it against all 8/1's. I was trying to do some sort of INDEX MATCH or the like to get it to work but nothing seemed to work.

Assume that I cannot sort the data by response time because it comes in timestamped and I want to be able to pull this down a long ways so as new data is added it will auto populate the percentile.

Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBaDl.jpg)

```
=PERCENTRANK.INC(INDEX($A$2:$C,MATCH(A2,$C$2:$C,0),3),C2)
```

Was hoping this would give me all same dates to match against.